# ngModel is not working with value attribute in ngx-material-timepicker with input in Angular7?

Tags: angular7

I have used ngx-material-timepicker for implementing the time filter.in our case time picker is open properly but its not working in the following scenarios:

**Case 1**  :

1.initially i have set selected time in the input and it working properly now this time i am not using with [(ngModel)]

```
<input [ngxTimepicker]="defaultValue" [value]="'05:11 pm'" (change)="selectChanged($event)">
<ngx-material-timepicker #defaultValue></ngx-material-timepicker><br>
```

**Case 2** :
2.Now we have add [(ngModel)] for get the selected value that is selected fro the picker but now this time out initially set value is not showing in the input but if i remove the [(ngModel)] its working:

```
    <input [ngxTimepicker]="defaultValue"  [(ngModel)]="date1" [value]="'05:11 pm'" (ngModelChange)="selectChanged($event)" >
<ngx-material-timepicker #defaultValue></ngx-material-timepicker><br>
```

I have also post above issue in the github but get any response,please tell me anyone how to fix above issue.

Comment: i have fixed above issue after cusomize code:                                                                            <input [ngxTimepicker]="defaultValue"  [(ngModel)]="date1  == undefined ? defaultValue : date1" [value]="'05:11 pm'" (ngModelChange)="selectChanged($event)" >

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem but in my case my inputs are into form and i forget about the name propriety.
i just added the name="date" in the input tag

```
  <mat-form-field class="toggle-example" style="width: 100%">
  <input matInput  [(ngModel)]="time" [ngxTimepicker]="toggleTimepicker"   name="time"   [format]="24" [disableClick]="true" readonly>
  <ngx-material-timepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="toggleTimepicker"></ngx-material-timepicker-toggle>
  <ngx-material-timepicker   #toggleTimepicker></ngx-material-timepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I have fixed issue via below code:**

<input [ngxTimepicker]="defaultValue" [(ngModel)]="date1 == undefined ? defaultValue : date1" [value]="'05:11 pm'" (ngModelChange)="selectChanged($event)" >

Answer (score 0):

I think the `onchange` that you were asking is to set the time 
You can use `[timeset]="(setTime())"` inside your `ngx-time-picker` tag
And in your `ts` file write the set time method.

Answer (score 0):

I used this step and succeeded

```
<mat-form-field>
<input aria-label="default time" matInput [ngxTimepicker]="defaultValue" [value]="'9:00 am'" readonly>
<ngx-material-timepicker (timeSet)="setTime($event)" #defaultValue>
</ngx-material-timepicker>
```